# right way to add starting tips in Android app

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application, and I want to show some tips (few slides) for user when applicationis started first time.

I can make an activity and start it in OnCreate method of main activity, or make dialog window.

I want to ask: how to make it in the right way? Can experienced developers advise something, maybe with example?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first make sure that these tips are launched only on first launch of app. I have seen this done by displaying a Dialog, and saving a value to shared preferences (or in sqlite for that matter). On next app launch this value is checked, if it is set, then you don't display the Dialogs.

This seems to be the simplest way. Note that when the app is uninstalled and installed by again the Dialogs will be displayed again.

Sometime we want to give the user ability to see this Dialogs once again. You can do this by setting/resetting the value in shared preferences from the apps settings screen. The user can change the value here and see the Dialogs again on app start.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a Dialog Type Activity and show it automatically  at the first time  startup of your application.
  and also add a help in you menu so that user can see it whenever he/she need help.